# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'FarseerPhysics.Dynamics.Fixture'

Tags: c#, farseer

I always get this error message in this line when I try to attach a fixture to a body.

```
Fixture Newfixture = FixtureFactory.AttachCompoundPolygon(list, 1.0f, TestBody);
```

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'FarseerPhysics.Dynamics.Fixture'

How can I create a fixture and attach it to a body? Is it possible to attach more than one fixture to a body?

The rest of my code:

```
List<Vertices> list = new List<Vertices>();
Vector2 _origin;
float _scale;

uint[] data = new uint[Sprite.Width * Sprite.Height];
Sprite.GetData(data);
Vertices textureVertices = PolygonTools.CreatePolygon(data, Sprite.Width, false);
Vector2 centroid = -textureVertices.GetCentroid();
textureVertices.Translate(ref centroid);
_origin = -centroid;
textureVertices = SimplifyTools.ReduceByDistance(textureVertices, 4f);
list = Triangulate.ConvexPartition(textureVertices, TriangulationAlgorithm.Bayazit);
_scale = 1f;
Vector2 vertScale = new Vector2(ConvertUnits.ToSimUnits(1)) * _scale;
foreach (Vertices vertices in list)
{
  vertices.Scale(ref vertScale);
}
```

Comment: `FixtureFactory.AttachCompoundPolygon` is returning a List not a single item.

Answer (score 0):

```
Fixture Newfixture = FixtureFactory.AttachCompoundPolygon(list, 1.0f, TestBody);
```

This line of code returns a `List<Fixture>`
Here is the method signature from the FixtureFactory source code.

```
public static List<Fixture> AttachCompoundPolygon(List<Vertices> list, float density, Body body)
```

So you're getting a `List<Fixture>` back. If you want to get the first item in that list (which might be the case, since you're assuming there'd be only one), then

```
    Fixture Newfixture = FixtureFactory.AttachCompoundPolygon(list, 1.0f, TestBody).First();
```

Comment: I want to attach 3 fixtures to TestBody. How can I do that?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. When you call AttachCompoundPolygon, with your list of vertices, you get multiple fixtures attached to the TestBody like that.